# Regular Expression - Get length x width and height in text

Tags: regex

I am having the following text and I would like to get as a result the values `200`, `90` and `14` seperately:

```
    FarbeWhite

    Artikelgewicht9 Kg

    Produktabmessungen200 x 90 x 14 cm

    MaterialSchaumstoffmatratze
```

I tried the following `*Produktabmessungen([^\r]*)` but I  only get an error back.

Any suggestions, what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: you cannot start a regex with `*`

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `(\d+) x (\d+) x (\d+)`
:)